# Manually emitting a value to an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I'm using rxjs in angular 6 application and I'm building a component which has a `downloadUrl: Observable<string>` which is populated when I fetch the url from firebase storage.

I need to assign an initial value which is passed to the component using the `@Input attribute (@Input imagesrc:string)` and I've tried emitting a value to the downloadurl as (in `ngOnInit`) :

```
let emitter;
this.downloadURL = Observable.create(e => emitter = e)
emitter.next(this.imagesrc);
```

However, this is incorrect since I'm receiving console error messages that `emitter` is undefined. How would I be able to manually emit the value of `imagesrc` into downloadURL?

Comment: You should subscribe first `downloadURL.subscribe()
      emitter.next();`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't quite understand your implementation there.

Let's say here's your `FileService`:

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileService {

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }

  upload(path: string, file: File): Observable<string> {
    return from(this.storage.upload(path, file))
      .pipe(switchMap(_ => this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL()));
  }

  delete(downloadUrl) {
    return this.storage.storage.refFromURL(downloadUrl).delete();
  }

}
```

Assuming that you want to expose an Observable with an initial value of `this.imagesrc` and then once you get the download url, you want to update the value of this Observable, you can try the below approach:

```
private emitter: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
emitter$: Observable<string> = this.emitter.asObservable();
...
constructor(private fileService: FileService) {}
...
ngOnChanges() {
  this.emitter.next(this.imagesrc);
}
...
functionWhereYouAreExpectingDownloadUrl() {
  ...
  this.fileService.upload(pathToStoreTheFileAt, fileToStore)
    .subscribe(downloadUrl => this.emitter.next(downloadUrl));
}
```

Here we're creating a `BehaviorSubject<string>` which can be initialized with `this.imagesrc`. But we've keeping this `private` and exposing this `asObservable`. And then as soon as we get the `downloadUrl` we call `next` on emitter to push new value to our `emitter$` `Observable`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, much appreciated. In your example you've indicated that I need to get the downloadURL first - however, I want to expose a download URL before the user has attempted to upload a file (I.e I want to display a placeholder image which would be in the imagesrc). One way I was thinking was to display a seperate image element and hide the element that was going to use the downloadURL. However, for this I would need to manage hiding/showing the two elements. I was hoping that I would be able to set the downloadURL when the component is initialised.